# Надо найти минимальное значение в списке в Python 3. Помогите найти ошибку

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, list

Задание: создайте функцию minimun, принимающую два аргумента (def minimum(x, y):...) и возвращающую минимум от них; используя эту функцию внутри цикла, найдите минимальное значение в списке numbers

Мой код:

```
numbers = [10, 20, 300, -1, -5, 1]

min=numbers[0]

#создаю функцию

def minimum (min,y):
    if min > y:
        min = y  

#нахожу наименьшее в списке

for n in numbers:
    minimum(min,n)


#печатаю наименьшее в списке

print(min)
```

Пожалуйста, помогите найти ошибку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас ошибка, потому что аргументы передаются по значению
По ссылке передаются только изменяемые типы данных (списки, словари и тд)
Решение тут только немного подправить вашу функцию **minimum**:

```
def minimun(a, b):
    return a if a < b else b

numbers = [10, 20, 300, -1, -5, 1]

min = numbers[0]

for elem in numbers:
    min = minimun (min, elem)

print (min)
```

Comment: Нужно заметить, что `min` - это название встроенной функции питона, лучше не использовать такое имя переменной, оно перекрывает встроенную функцию.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random


my_list = [random.randint(-20, 20) for i in range(20)]
def min_abl(a, b):
    return a if a < b else b


def min_el(my_list):
    minm = my_list[0]
    for i in my_list:
        minm = min_abl(minm, i)
    return minm


print("min =", min_el(my_list))
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]